# Get the range of string in lua in row and column

Tags: lua

I'm trying to calculate the range of a given text in terms of row and column.

For following string,

```
'hello\nworld
```

The range should be

```
{
    row_start = 0,
    col_start = 0,
    row_end = 1,
    col_end = 4
}
```

Here, `row_start` and `col_start` are NOT important for the question. `world` will be in the second line hens the `row_end` is 1. `world` has 5 characters hens the `col_end` is 4.

So, I need a function to calculate the number of line breaks and length of the string at the last line to calculate the range.

I couldn't find any other way than calculating the number of line breaks to get `row_end`. Then reverse the text and find the index of the first newline character to get the `col_end`. Any other efficient way to do this in Lua?

Answer (score 1):

Given `str = "hello\nworld"`:

> I couldn't find any other way than calculating the number of line breaks to get `row_end`

There is no more efficient way: You have to count the line breaks. Assuming UNIX LFs as in your example, you can simply use `gmatch` for this (which is presumably more efficient than abusing `gsub` to do the counting for you):

```lua
local row_end = 0
for _ in str:gmatch"\n" do row_end = row_end + 1 end
```

> Then reverse the text and find the index of the first newline character to get the `col_end`. Any other efficient way to do this in Lua?

Yes, this is indeed needlessly inefficient. The shortest way to do this Lua would be using pattern matching:

```lua
local col_end = #str - str:find"[^\n]*$"
```

Explanation: Find the starting index of the longest "run" of non-newline characters. For `str`, this would be the index of `w`. Then subtract this index from the length of the string to find the 0-based index of the last character.

A probably more efficient solution would just remember the index after the last newline (and thus have no issue with possibly poor pattern matching performance):

```lua
local after_last_newline_idx = 1
for idx in str:gmatch"\n()" do -- () captures the position after the newline
    after_last_newline_idx = idx
end
local col_end = #str - after_last_newline_idx
```

This could be merged with the first loop to only loop once:

```lua
local row_end = 0
local after_last_newline_idx = 1
for idx in str:gmatch"\n()" do -- () captures the position after the newline
    row_end = row_end + 1
    after_last_newline_idx = idx
end
local col_end = #str - after_last_newline_idx
```

... taking linear time, which is required. However this avoids creating a garbage string by reversing `str`. It only loops over the string once to find newlines. If `gmatch` is too slow for your purposes, you can easily use `string:byte` or `string:sub` and a numeric for loop to do the looping over newlines yourself.